# Reading data and saving as csv

Tags: node.js

I asked a similar question, but changed my code a bit, enough to warrant deleting it and asking it again (different error message).

I would like to pull data from an [API built on node.js](https://github.com/boxing/boxrec)

and save this data as a csv. This is the code I have written:

```
const boxrec = require("boxrec").Boxrec;
(async function () {
    try {
        const cookieJar = await boxrec.login('xx','xxxx');
    } catch(e) {
        console.log("Login error: " + e);
    }
});
(async function () {
    var person = await boxrec.getPersonById(cookieJar,352);
});
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('testing.csv',person,'utf8')
```

Running this returns this error message:

> fs.writeFile('testing.csv',person,'utf8')
>                              ^ ReferenceError: person is not defined

Answer (score 0):

You messed up a scope of your program a bit. Person is undefined because it is inside your async function. Do this:

```
var fs = require('fs');

(async function () {
    var person = await boxrec.getPersonById(cookieJar,352);
    fs.writeFile('testing.csv',person,'utf8')
});
```

Comment: Thanks, tried making the suggested changes and running the code, but the testing.csv file isn't being created..even tried specifying where it should be stored

Comment: What happens if you add console.log(person) above writting file function? Do you get the data?

Comment: I do not get anything

Comment: Ok. So there is your problem right there. Your API call is not functioning as it should.

Comment: maybe i'm not running my code right. I am running it by writing node filename.js on the visual studio code terminal

Answer (score 0):

the variable `person` is defined inside the function you are having scope issue check!

[the scope doc](https://www.sitepoint.com/demystifying-javascript-variable-scope-hoisting/)

Comment: Thanks, change the code up based on Lazar's answer, but csv file still isn't being created (no error message now)